# Can I link to a review I wrote on Rotten Tomatoes?

Tags: links

I'm trying to email a link to a review I wrote on RT. I can't find a link of any kind.

Is it not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In brief, no.

User reviews only appear in a few places on Rotten Tomatoes (i.e. on a page related to either the movie or the reviewer) and always in list with other reviews without so much as an anchor tag to link to. It is hard to even reliably link to a page with your review on it, since other reviews will bump it.

If you are keen to share your reviews, you may want to consider posting elsewhere (IMDB will show reviews individually or you could start your own blog).